# Simple AtomPub server library

Tags: python, http, atom-feed, atompub

What simple [AtomPub](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) server libraries with file- or DB-based backends can you recommend? Unix-style servers that "do one thing, do it well" are especially welcome.

Maybe even libraries in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

http://atomserver.codehaus.org/

If someone is looking for a library to use in building Atompub into an existing service, they should definitely use Abdera directly. AtomServer, by contrast, is a full java web application that can be up and running in a few minutes by configuring a database and a few XML configuration files. It addresses all of the metadata and content management pieces that Abdera doesn't, and it's undergone a lot of battle-hardening to make it rock-solid and performant. Our goal moving forward is to make AtomServer easily interoperable with any spec-compliant Atom Client, while making the deployment of a server as easy as possible, with as little coding as possible.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/atomserver

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Atom-Server-Berry-Jacob

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll take a look at AtomServer.

Answer (score 1):

[`amplee`](http://trac.defuze.org/wiki/amplee) is an AtomPub library and server in Python. It haven't been actively developed since 2009. I am not aware of projects that use it.

The link was found via [Dan Diephouse](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/qcon-diephouse-atom).

Answer (score 1):

AtomServer is certainly a mature Atom server framework:
http://atomserver.codehaus.org/

AtomServer is in a fleshed out Abdera server (Abdera is an abstract library that can be used to create a server - but in itself is not a server).

AtomServer is covered by a series of infoQ articles starting at:
http://www.infoq.com/articles/atomserver

Careful with the articles, however. **The** Tim Bray highlights shortcomings in them whereby AtomServer implementation details may be misinterpreted as Atom standards.  Thus, if you're happy to adopt an existing set of Atom extensions, and are keen to get up and running quickly, AtomServer is for you. If you're keen to adhere to pure Atom, then either create your own Adbdera instance or have a look into eXist at http://exist.sourceforge.net/atompub.html

[You may get more targeted advice if you give a few more details on your requirement: languange, data throughput, existing standads, ...]